# Is there any way that I can open 10000 files in parallel on linux to reach the open file limit?

Tags: linux

I am trying to understand the behaviour of my code when I reach the max number of file descriptors that can be opened. Is there any way that I can open 100000 files in parallel to reproduce this issue?

Comment: How do you use to open a single file?

Comment: You could create 100 threads that each open 1000 files.

Comment: I use vim to open a single file

Comment: You need to write a program in a language like C.

Comment: @Barmar can you give me a sample command?

Comment: not possible on shell? possibly use xargs??

Comment: It might be possible, but it will take forever.

Comment: Are you trying to reach the system-wide limit or the per-process limit?

Comment: system wide should also work I guess

Comment: but how would I reach the process wide limit?

Comment: Is it ok for you to open all the files windows-stacked in a same vim instance? I mean, something like: `vim -o [$(for ((i = 1; i <= 100000 ; i++)); do echo $i.txt; done)]`

Comment: It is. But it too long. I used gdb to reduce the limit for that particular process instead. You can take a look at this link, https://gchp.ie/updating-ulimit-on-running-linux-process/

Comment: I think we can mark this as answered?